# converting union sql query to cakehp array method

Tags: sql, cakephp, union

This is a very straight forward question and don't expect code but possibly a pointer to a good tutorial or some tips as I have no clue.. I am attempting to put this query in cakephp's array method when calling from the database.

```
SELECT thickness, colto_section, Position
FROM (

SELECT thickness, colto_section,base_layers.position AS Position
FROM base_layers
WHERE base_layers.section_id =1
UNION 
SELECT thickness, colto_section,selects.position
FROM selects
WHERE selects.section_id =1
UNION 
SELECT thickness, colto_section,subbases.position
FROM subbases
WHERE subbases.section_id =1
)x
ORDER BY Position ASC
```

Thanks, even just to declare union in the array will help xD.

Edit: this code provided is working 100%.

update:

What I am attempting to do.
I have 3 tables, with some similar data eg. thickness, colto_section, Position.
each table represents a different layer of a road, and needs to be in order so
that we know which to put first. usually base_layer is first but after that it
can be anything. so....

The codes query I have done, does exactly this.
I could go do this->query(); but that defeats the point
of cakephp's framework and security. so trying to find out
if there is a way to bring the union into Cakephp's array 
method of calling data from the database.

So main question is can this query be converted to Cakephp's
array method? if so, a tip pls ;)

(excuse repetition, trying to be thorough)

Comment: Why don't you join these tables instead of using union?

Comment: well, honestly because I don't know the join method to well, and got the correct results using union... so yeah stuck with it. Is there no functionality in cakephp for union....?

Comment: select * from base_layers as bl
 left join selects as sl
  on(sl.section_id = bl.section_id)
 left join subbases as sb
  on(sb.section_id = bl.section_id)
where bl.section_id = 1

Comment: see this simple join query if it works for you then you can use join

Comment: thanks, it works and joins them, pulling the correct fields... but how do I do my ordering after I have the joined query? or must I first bring the data out with cakephp then do my conditions while pulling data out..?

Comment: No you can use order by clause in the join query itself

Comment: hmm trying but saying something is invalid... On my screen it is pulling the fields and putting them next to each other, if that is the output, with the ordering put it from right to left then. instead of top to bottom? ( sorry for all the questions really appreciate the help)...

Comment: I am sorry, I am not getting your point, can you pls put the whole scenario in the question then I can answer it probably..